# How old was Thanos at the start of Endgame?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame, thanos

I am obviously talking about *Avengers: Infinity War* Thanos, who died in the beginning of *Avengers: Endgame*.

How old was he when he died? I am seeing all over the internet that he was thousands of years old, but I don't see any proper citation.

I saw his earliest footage when he was conquering Gamora's planet, but that should be few decades ago at most, because Gamora was a little kid at that time.

How old was Thanos when Thor chopped his head off? Any words from writers/ directors/ producers or any educated guess?

Comment: We don't know how fast Gamora is aging.

Comment: He's much younger in the (decanonised) novels

Comment: Can we freeze-frame the severed head scene and count the rings?

Comment: He was Inevitable years old.

Comment: I would imagine we'll get more clarification based on his role in Eternals. Part of that movie will take place thousands of years in the past. If Thanos is a part of that portion of the movie, then he'll be far older, like he is in the comics, rather than the Russo comment below.

Comment: I know this is kinda off topic, but when considering Thanos age, should it be considered Titan's revolutions or Earth revolutions?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In an interview with ComicBook.com -- partially quoted in a [Screen Rant article](https://screenrant.com/avengers-endgame-thanos-genghis-khan-comparison/) -- Joe Russo (co-director on *Avengers: Infinity War* and *Avengers: Endgame*, along with his brother, Anthony) stated that MCU Thanos is a thousand years old:

> **Clearly, Thanos, you know, is a thousand-year-old character** who has fought everyone in the universe. He's the greatest. He's the Genghis Khan of the universe. He would have the greatest weapon.

The full interview was posted on YouTube. The question Russo was responding to there is asked about 25 minutes in:

Comment: Do they mean he's literally 1,000 (with his 1001th birthday coming up), or more generally "he's at least a thousand, he's really old..."?

Comment: Russo didn't offer any further clarification on that in that particular interview. The question was really about the nature of the blade he used to destroy Cap's shield, and Russo just happened to mention that Thanos was _"a thousand-year-old character"_ in passing. Given that it was only mentioned in passing, I'd be inclined to take it as a rough figure rather than a precise one. I've been checking out other interviews with the Russo brothers, and if I turn up any more info which sheds further light on this question, I'll add it to the answer.

Comment: Russo clearly meant he was 1,000 years old exactly - down to the exact day of his birth! 